# How to get ESP8266 firmware version?

Tags: esp8266, communication, firmware

I am going to update the firmware of an ESP8266 module, but first I would like to know the current version or name.

How can I get it? Maybe with an AT command?

This is my ESP8266 module:

[image: My ESP8266 module.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESP8266 and the AT firmware are products of Espressif. They have everything documented on the [web site](http://espressif.com/en/support/download/overview?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14).

The AT command for version is `AT+GMR`.