# How to get version of Arduino board remotely

Tags: esp8266webserver

I have multiple Arduino WeMos D1 boards, with a mix of versions bought months apart.  One of these boards is working but I need to update it and I am not sure if it is R1 or R2 (the pinouts are different).  I do not have physical access to it (it is 200+ miles away in an area that is locked down) but I can connect through another device over WiFi.

It has the following included:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
```

So, I can even browse to a Webserver to run commands.  How can I add to the code (or even replace it) to return a value that tells me which version the board is?  According to [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/47321/26515) you can do it with an AT command, but I am not sure how to pass an AT command from the WebServer interface (or any other way).

EDIT: I guess I may have confused the issue with my phrasing.  I can connect to the board and upload a new sketch (using OTA).  My question is, can I put something in a new sketch to determine the board details and upload it.  Once I get that, I can then put in a the actual sketch that I want.

Comment: If you upload your own sketch it replaces the AT firmware. Do you have the original code you burned to it? That would indicate (based on pin defs) which version--in hindsight, it's *always* a good idea to track what software goes onto which board, e.g., by MAC address or sthng.

Comment: the AT command is for AT firmware version, not for board id. the software running on esp8266 doesn't have to know the pinout of the board. io 5 is still io 5 no matter where it is on board's headers. so unless you have something special in your sketch what tells you the version of board set at compilation, there is no way to know if it is a D1 (R1) or D1 R2

Comment: @Juraj The two versions use different ESP8266 modules - 12B/E vs 12F. There may be a way (in software) to find that out.

Comment: you could replace the sketch with a new simple one that compares the boards config names to a numeric literal, ex: `if(D4==2){...}`. Make sure you have OTA on your test sketch. Then reflash the board with the current sketch. This is why I moved to an interpreted language on top of arduino c: you can see the code from SPIFFS in plain text, edit it from the web, and re-run, all w/o flahsing.

Comment: @dandavis Can you elaborate?  Which language?  Links?

Comment: @Majenko that sounds promising.  Perhaps that AT command or similar that I linked to? But how do I use it?

Comment: @Majenko and Chiwda, not with currently uploaded sketch. but I doubt it with any program. it is still the same esp8266 chip. you may get the serial number but I am not sure if that would help you.

Comment: I don't need to do it with the currently uploaded sketch!  I can upload a new one (as I said in my question "...or even replace it...") and then, when I have determined the correct version, put the correct sketch back on there.

Comment: I think about all you'd be able to do is exercise the board itself, e.g., is something connected to some pin, that's different on the two versions you created. Or if the code allows you to *read* the code that's on the board you might be able to reverse-engineer it to figure out what pins are defined as what. It's super-important to understand what code is deployed where. The *easiest* solution is to have somebody take a picture of it and send it to you.

Comment: dave is on the right track about reading the hex back off.  search "rip code off arduino" to find a forum post that may be relevant.  Once you have it, compare to your code's builds

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do with your currently loaded sketch. The board can *only* do exactly what you have programmed it to do and nothing more.

- There *are* no "AT" commands. They only exist if you load the AT firmware instead of your own firmware
- You can't magically make your code do things it wasn't programmed to do<sup>1</sup>

However the only real differences between the two boards is the version of the ESP8266 module in use: ESP-12E vs ESP-12F, (and the *only* difference between those modules is the layout of the PCB antenna in order to achieve FCC certification) and the addition of some unpopulated serial and I2C pins.

<s>Aside from that the only other differences are purely cosmetic or of no consequence to your software.</s>

So it really doesn't matter which board you have or which you compile your code for.

---

<sup>1: Unless you can cause some buffer overflow and inject new code into memory to execute, but to do that you'd need to be a l33t h4x0r.</sup>

---

**Addendum:**

It appears they have two boards, named the same, with different pin arrangements (both sadly very stupidly designed, but there you are).  All I can suggest is compile for one, install it, and see if it works. If it doesn't, then compile for the other and see if that works.

Or compile some special firmware that will probe what you have attached and work out what is attached where - then install and run that.

Comment: the problem is that on the same header pin R1 has a different io pin then R2.

Comment: @Juraj Well that's stupid of them, isn't it? TBH the pinouts of *both* boards are just stupid, since there are far more "pins" than the ESP8266 actually has, so the pinout is pretty much meaningless.